# Azure giving HTTP 500 Error when using IConfigurationBuilder.Build

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm trying to follow this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-aspnet-core-app?tabs=core5x and it's working locally and I can grab the connection string just fine with this code.

```
var settings = config.Build();
var connection = settings.GetConnectionString("AppConfig");
```

The problem comes when I publish to Azure, I get an HTTP 500 error. I've tried turning on every type of logs I can, I was even trying to TryCatch in the Main method to see if I could see the actual error but all logging is doing is sending me the HTML of the error page. Any help? If anyone knows why that would break Azure, that would be great or show me how to actually get real detailed error messages so I can see what's breaking. For now I've just hard coded the connection string which then works just fine.

[image: Azure App Logs Settings]

Comment: Does your application has got read access to the config files?

Comment: Yes. When I hardcode the connection string it works. And its Azure so I assume this should work since it's from a guide for Azure from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove unused namespaces, build solution, and re-deploy the site to azure.
2. When a website is hosted in an Azure VM, 500 (5XX) errors won't occur. However, sites hosted in Azure Web Apps may encounter these issues. The mounting of Azure Web App files utilizing remote file storage might occasionally cause connection problems with the remote storage.

This can cause the application (App Manager) to be restarted leading to 500 errors. The following steps can be taken to reduce the chances of these errors occurring:

- Change the `dss.config` file's settings to use Azure Table storage rather than a physical file.
- Set up Azure Storage to save the log file rather than a physical file.
- Enable the option [Local Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-local-cache) by adding the key `WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION = Always` in the Azure Portal > Web App > Application Settings.

**Note**: Enabling Local Cache mode may take some time to activate after setting the key. To check to see if it is enabled:

- Go to  `https://<YOURSITE>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ProcessExplorer/`
- Click “**Properties**” and verify that the environment variable  **WEBSITE_LOCALCACHE_READ**  is set to  **true**

If you're unable to get the application running successfully, I would like to suggest you, refer this  [troubleshooting page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-dotnet-visual-studio#a-namedetailederrorlogsaview-detailed-error-message-logs) to know how to get the detailed error message logs along with few tips, while publishing to azure app service.